# Updating state parent-of-parent component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

New to React native and looking for a tip on how to do this best.

I have a screen component containing a modal component, and the modal contains a Contacts component with a checkbox list of Contacts. Upon hitting a button in the modal, I want to update the state of the screen component.

```
<Modal animationType="slide" 
    transparent={false} 
    visible={this.state.contactModalVisible} 
    onRequestClose={()=> {
        this.setState({ contactModalVisible: false});
    }}>
    <ContactList // On pressAButtonInsideHere, how do I update the Screen state? />
</Modal>
```

Should I put the button inside the Modal component and have the ContactList component update the Modal component first? Or can I update the screen straight from ContactList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid to update screen state from a nested component (ie something inside of your `<ContactList />` component). There are a number of approaches to this, and the most suitable approach will depend on your requirements. A simple way to do this however would be to add a callback to `<ContactList />`.

So for instance, you could add the following `onButtonPress` callback:

```
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  transparent={false}
  visible={this.state.contactModalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    this.setState({ contactModalVisible: false});
  }}>
  <ContactList onButtonPress={ () => this.setState({ yourChange : true }) }
    // On pressAButtonInsideHere, how do I update the Screen state?
  />
</Modal>
```

And then update your `<ContactList />` component to fire the `onButtonPress` callback when an (internal) button component is pressed. To illustrate the general idea, consider this mock for `<ContactList />`:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native'

const ContactList = () => {

  return (<Button onPress={ () => this.props.onButtonPress() } 
                  title="Button in contact list" />)
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you Dacre Denny. What I was missing was the 'props' in this.props.onButtonPress()